# App is automatically redirecting back to previous page

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a link in my navigation toolbar which is in the footer. When I am on a page, and click on the nav link, It brings me to `#the-page` for a split second, but then I get redirected back to the page I was previously on.

Anyone else run into this problem?`

```
$('#page-link').on('click', function() {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#the-page", {  } );
});
```

Comment: why are you passing an empty object `{ }`? are you using any other js code?

Comment: No reason, was just copy pasted from somewhere. Just removed it. Yes there's about 600 lines of other js code unfortunately.

Comment: Then you need to check which line is causing this problem. you shouldn't be redirected without a reason.

Answer (score 0):

This on click was in a pageshow function of the page that was showing for a split second

```
    $('.ui-listview').on('click', 'li.latest-news', function() {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#single-article", { } );
    });
```

by moving it to a pageinit function it seemed to fix it.

It turns out this was a rebinding problem, I added a console.log inside of this function, and realized it was being called multiple times per click.